# Numpy array dimension

Tags: python, numpy

```
In [21]: a = np.array([1,2,3])

In [22]: a.shape
Out[22]: (3,)
```

What's the difference between `(3,)` and `(3,1)` in shape?

Why isn't the output `(,3)` or `(1,3)`? This is a 1 by 3 matrix, right?

Comment: This is a 1d array. not 1 X 3 matrix, a 1X3 matrix looks like [[1,2,3]].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  A 1x3 matrix would be a two-dimensional array (e.g., `np.array([[1, 2, 3]])`).  What you have is a one-dimensional array of length three.  In mathematical terms, a 1D array roughly corresponds to a vector.